# Drupal: how to rate node filefields?

Tags: drupal, cck, rating

I have a node type called 'movie' which may contain several subtitle files using the CCK FileField module. Now I'm dealing with FiveStars module, I need to rate each subtitle separately! so the user should rate for subtitles associated with a movie, not the movie itself.
confused enough! any idea?

Comment: I think my way of asking this, made you think that it's not programming related. it absolutely is!

Comment: it is a web development question indeed.

Comment: If this one is closed, a lot of other web development questions should be closed as well. However, I don't agree. Although this is not a programming question per se, the answer might involve programming. It simply depends if somebody already did the programming for you; the OP could not have known that beforehand. IMHO stackoverflow is the most appropriate site for this question when compared to siblings like serverfault or doctype.

Comment: It's considerable that I've done this by "Programming" at last!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is going to be a tough one as the whole FiveStars module isn't really built for rating anything but nodes. (so rating fields is probably out)

You could use "[content multigroup](http://mostrey.be/cck-3-introducing-multigroup-module)" and that will allow you to pair up your file fields with an integer field. Note that content multigroup was a standalong module but is now being integrated with [CCK3](http://drupal.org/project/cck) which is still in development. Even with this, you will have to attach a JavaScript ratings tool (not a drupal module persay) to the field on your own as I'm pretty sure FiveStars is only designed to work against nodes, not specific fields, even less so for the multigroup fields.

So, if you want to stick to using FiveStars and as it's designed (not rewriting it to work with individual fields/multigroup), I'm pretty sure your only option is to split the subtitles into a separate content type and associate using nodereference. This will give the unfortunate side effect of having a separate page to actually do the reviewing. It certainly won't be as quick to rate a series of subtitles.

That's what I know from what I've used of those modules.

Comment: +1 for turning subtitles into content-types.
however, you can use views to display all of the subtitles uploaded for a given movie. panels (with the node_view page) can be used to display both the movie_node and the subtitle view at once, and also makes it a lot easier to pass in the arguments...